# Changing bootstrap.scss file

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to customize Bootstrap 4 via Sass. The thing is, I want to wrap the imports in a few classes, to make sure it'll affect only those parts of website I want.

Something like:

```
.page-one,
.page-two {
    /* imports go here */
}
```

When I just customize it, change the styling, the name of the main bootstrap.scss file, it works. The moment I wrap it in classes, the browser doesn't recognize it at all.

Am I doing something wrong? Should I not be wrapping it like that? And if not, then how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the imports, but the **html tag** must have class the `page-one` or `page-two` etc..

Comment: Hey! Yes, but I do have it. I've wrapped my entire content in a class(for example page-one) and it still doesn't apply. I've tried using body.page-one, too. But that does nothing, either. I'm lost, honestly.